# Поиск по шаблону в БД MS SQL

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть БД в которой нужно сделать поиск по шаблону. База данных выглядит как представлено на рисунке ниже.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается реализовать поиск по шаблону. Отправляю команду:

```
SELECT * FROM People_list WHERE FIO LIKE 'Куприенко Демид Мартынович'
```

В итоге мне возвращается пустая таблица, как будто данного значения в БД не встречается. Подскажите, в чем ошибся? Спасибо.

**UPDATE**

Запросы приведенные ниже тоже не работают.

```
SELECT * FROM People_list WHERE FIO LIKE N'Куприенко Демид Мартынович'
SELECT * FROM People_list WHERE FIO LIKE '%Куприенко%'
```

Comment: Если у вас поиск по шаблону, то необходимо использовать `%` в вашем примере будет так `FIO LIKE '%Куприенко%`

Comment: @vikolyada В принципе совершенно не обязательно, без `%` like работает как обычное `=` и в принципе должен найти записи.

Comment: Отправляете "команду" откуда ? нет ли там проблем с кодировкой. Если из того же кода вставить запись в БД русские буквы так же читаются. И убедитесь, что в значениях в БД у Куприенко нет каких нибудь латинских букв в ФИО случайно или пробела лишнего

Comment: Какой тип у колонки fio? Nvarchar? Nchar?

Comment: @PashaPash♦, у колонки FIO тип nvarchar.
@Mike, проблем с кодировкой нет, строка FIO полностью идентична строке в запросе, пробелов лишних нет.

Comment: Для типа `NVARCHAR` нужно использовать префикс `N`: `N'Куприенко'`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov работать будет и без префикса.

Comment: @Denis что бы убедиться что строка полностью идентична, скопируйте строку из запроса поиска, и вставьте ее в строку БД. магии быть не может, строки различаются

Comment: @teran, я так и делаю, но не работает почему то

Comment: точно? а не наоборот копируете из таблицы и вставляете в поиск? я вам предлагаю обратно, сделать update таблицы для этого id. и повторить поиск

Comment: @teran _"работать будет и без префикса"_. Если collation БД (в контексте которой выполняется запрос) не кириллический, то не сработает.

Comment: @Denis приведите минимальный пример для воспроизведения, включая схему базы. Попробуйте выполнить select без where, потом минимизировать его до `fio like N'о'` - мало ли, вы запросы выполняете не на той базе, на которой данные проверяете. Или вообще не выполняете. Или данных в базе нет на самом деле.

Comment: Попробуйте `SELECT * FROM People_list WHERE FIO LIKE N'%Куприенко%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом научного тыка выяснил что запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
"SELECT * FROM People_list WHERE [FIO] LIKE N'%Куприенко Демид Мартынович%'"
```

Пришлось FIO заключить в квадратные скобки, добавить префикс N и символы %.

Comment: Квадратные скобки не должны влиять на результат, % - тоже (если у вас в начале и конце строки нет лишних пробелов, например, из-за типа колонки nchar, а не nvarchar).

Comment: скорее там какой нибудь `#13#10` в конце был. надо было с `ltrim(rtrim(fio)) like ...` проверить.